# javascript onblur onMouseOver calculate tax and autofill form input

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

After 2 days searching I give up. I have a form and need to add (autofill) taxes to the input total price but in a easy simple way:

```
<form name="form" action="go.php">

<input name="cost" type="text">

<input name="costplustax" type="text" value=" here we autofill cost +19%>

<input type="submit" value="ready to mysql">
```

I can nothing about javascript tested a lot of examples but all complicated. I just need to autofill the input costplustax with cost plus tax

example

cost 100.000
because tax is 19% then we autofilll the input with onblur or onMouseOver to
119.000

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First  add an ID to your elements (this makes referencing the elements with JS easier).  Ex

```
<input name="cost" type="text">
```

becomes

```
<input name="cost" ID="cost" type="text">
```

You need to add a script tag to house the JS code like this

```
<script>
  var taxPerc = .19; 
  document.getElementById("cost").onblur = function(){
    document.getElementById("costplustax").value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cost").value) * (1.00 + taxPerc)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: adding an `id` attribute would be better, inputs need to names to function correctly as form elements

Comment: Tested but is not autofilling <form name="form" action="go.php">

<input name="cost" ID="cost" type="text">

<input name="costplustax" ID="costplustax" type="text" value="">

<input type="submit" value="ready to mysql">

Comment: The script tag should be placed after your <input> tags.  Preferably right before the closing <form> tag

Comment: Lol my error was that </form> tag was missing. It is working now and you saved my day. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form name="form" action="go.php">
        <input id='cost' name="cost" type="text">
        <input id='costplustax' name="costplustax" type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="ready to mysql">
    </form>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var cost=document.getElementById('cost');
        var cpt=document.getElementById('costplustax');

        function prefill(event){
            var cv=parseFloat( cost.value );
            if( cv && !isNaN( cv ) ) cpt.value=cv + cv * 0.19;
        }
        cost.addEventListener('blur',prefill,false );
    </script>
```